# Import Erlang project into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, erlang

I am new to erlang. I want to *import* existing erlang project into eclipse. I have installed *Erlide* plugin for Eclipse (Java, Luno). I am able to create an *Erlang project* but, to **import** an Erlang project, (as per the link: http://erlide.sourceforge.net/erlide.html#import_project ) I'm not able to find the option Erlang to select in the *import wizard* so that I can import the project.

I even did ([Erlang updates](http://erlide.org/update)) and installed updates. But still, not able to find Erlang import option in the wizard.
 Please help me. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is old. You have to create a new project and point it to the location of your existing source code. Let me know if you see any more problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Step : Goto **File -> Import -> General -> Existing projects into workspace.** , then browse your project folder. and change any settings, if you want and then finish it.

Finally your **Erlang** project will be loaded.

Note:-->Tested on Eclipse mars 2, it worked. Thumbs up!!!!